# Is the evolution of a density matrix linear with respect to density matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, linear-algebra, density-operator, time-evolution

The evolution of a density matrix in quantum mechanics is given by
$$i\hbar\dot\rho=[H,\rho]=H \rho-\rho H.$$    If it is linear, can be written the rhs as  $A \rho$ for a linear operator $A$?

Comment: Do you know what superoperators are? See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoperator#Example_von_Neumann_Equation) or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207051/quantum-and-classical-liouville-operators) to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Short answers : yes and yes.

The equation of motion for the density matrix, namely von Neumann's equation $\dot{\rho} = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\rho]$, is linear with respect to $\rho$, as expected, since the commutator is bilinear. We can check it again, in order to convince ourselves :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\partial_t(\lambda_1\rho_1+\lambda_2\rho_2) 
   &=& 
   -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\lambda_1\rho_1+\lambda_2\rho_2] \\
   &=& 
   -\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(H(\lambda_1\rho_1+\lambda_2\rho_2) - (\lambda_1\rho_1+\lambda_2\rho_2)H\right) \\
   &=& 
   -\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\lambda_1(H\rho_1-\rho_1H) + \lambda_2(H\rho_2-\rho_2H)\right) \\
   &=& 
   -\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\lambda_1[H,\rho_1] + \lambda_2[H,\rho_2]\right) \\
   &=& 
   \lambda_1\dot{\rho}_1 + \lambda_2\dot{\rho}_2
\end{array}
$$
As it is linear, it can be rewritten as $\dot{\rho} = A\rho$, with $A = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\,\cdot\,]$; however, since $A$ is a linear operator acting itself on a vector space made of linear operators, it is called a *superoperator*, as mentioned by Tobias Fünke in the comment section, in order to emphasize that $A$ and $\rho$ do not live in the same spaces.